# How to disable cache of Apache?

Tags: apache, caching

I put only index.html in /var/www/html.
The page doesn't update after I changed the contents of index.html and reload.

I already disable cache_module in httpd.conf like this below.

```
# LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
# LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
```

Comment: Where is `httpd.conf`? I can't find it anywhere in `/etc` or `/var` on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

if you are using htaccess then you can do like

```
#Initialize mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
  FileETag None
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 12 Jan 1980 05:00:00 GMT"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Thank you! But where do I put this settings? I put it the end of httpd.conf and nothing changed..

Comment: create a .htaccess file under root directory where you have uploaded your files in server and put above lines inside .htaccess file

Comment: I did that but the result is not change. I also restarted apache.

Comment: check if you have mod_rewrite enable in the server with the hosting company. also check I have edited answer above

Comment: Thank you very much! I exchange the .htaccess to your new one. And the result doesn't change. I didn't use hosting service. I user vagrant as a server.

Comment: Then probably you do not need this .htaccess and change the line EnableSendfile on to EnableSendfile off in Apache config file

Comment: The problem solved!!!! Thank you for answering this entry-level question. I'll learn about EnableSendfile option soon;)

Comment: That `.htaccess` does not work for me. Also, my `apache2.conf` file did not contain `EnableSendfile on`, but I added `EnableSendfile off` and it doesn't work, it's still caching.

Comment: You may also need to enable the required modules, and reload Apache: `a2enmod headers rewrite && apachectl graceful`