# CSS / HTML / JS not updating XAMPP (local development)

Tags: php, magento, server, xampp, magento2

I've tried to install Magento 2 locally using XAMPP. This works fine, except for the fact that when I alter my CSS, HTML or JS, XAMPP won't get the updated files. It just takes the file I initially created with it's content, but not the updated version.

I think this has something to do with caching of Apache itself? I read something about disable cache using .htaccess (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_cache.html) but I can't figure out how to implement this.

Anyone knows how I can fix this?

Flushing cache doesn't work. Deploy static content may work, but I don't want to do that every time I make one minor change in the CSS (when I worked remotely, I did not have to do that either)

I think this problem is not Magento related, but rather something with XAMPP (probably Apache).

I have developer mode enabled.

Answer (score 0):

> Press Ctrl-F5 to hard refresh the page (to not use Browser's cache).
>
> If you still see the previous pages or changes, then Apache has
>   mod_cache caching them, or PHP has its opcode cache settings set to
>   not refresh changes for X amount of time.

Taken from [Xampp and Ampps don't reload files when changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308810/xampp-and-ampps-dont-reload-files-when-changed)

If mod_cache that is causing the problem then this might help you implement the fix [How to disable cache of Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891965/how-to-disable-cache-of-apache)

Comment: Inserting the said content in the .htaccess in the root of Magento 2 doesn't work unfortunately. Hard refresh won't do it either.

Comment: Damn sorry I've no experience with Magento so I'm out of suggestions.

Comment: No problem mate

Answer (score 0):

This is not a caching issue, but rather the deploy mode you're using.

You are probably in default mode, in which case you will have to deploy static content every time, however you can switch to developer mode.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html

This will stop magento having the need to generate the static content as it's done on the fly  via the use of symlinks etc.

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Or alternatively you can manually set this inside

```
app/etc/env.php
```

If developer mode isn't working it's more than likely down to permissions etc

Delete all files inside pub/static apart from the htaccess file, and make sure it's writable

Comment: I already had developer mode enabled and `bin/magento deploy:mode:show` returns that I am in developer mode. Before I had the issue that my frontend generated a lot of js errors, and `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` fixed this. But can using this command be the cause of not seeing changes on my website? Because it deployed the static content (and that may not work with developer mode?)

Comment: You need to make sure pub/static is empty apart from the htaccess and that it's writable. It won't be if you have run static deploy

Comment: Okay, so I then presumably come back to my old problem: the css / js / html not loading which I need to fix another way. Probably some permissions so need to find out how to do that on Windows the same way as on Mac / Linux

Comment: That can be due to permissions if magento can't create the symlinks on the fly. Make sure htaccess exists in pub/static and that rewrites are enabled in apache.

Comment: If you use setup:static-content:deploy -f then you will have to do this every time you make changes to your css etc, where has if you don't and use developer mode it with auto update.

Answer (score 0):

In developer mode, M2 does not generate static files. It should create symlinks to them from the various modules. If you however have ran setup:static-content:deploy and have those files in place, it won't update them. Try to delete only those files inside pub/static folder on which you've worked and see if Magento links to them. If you delete all contents of pub/static/ folder, pages will take very long to load in browser.

Comment: How do I check if Magento links to the correct files?

Comment: it will show the windows shortcut icon in place of actual file in pub/static/ folder.