# Reload from server for all files

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

I know it's possible to force reload from server using `location.reload(true)`. However, let's say I used that to refresh index.html. If index.html loads a bunch of javascript files, those are still coming from the cache for me. Is there any way to ignore the cache for the duration of a request?

My use case is that I'm doing AB testing on my app, and want to provide a way for users to go back to the old version if something isn't working. But some of the URLs are the same, even though the files between versions are different. It would be nice to be able to handle this in JS rather than having to change every URL on the new version.

Comment: since this is for testing, have you tried disabling caching server-side? That should make any reload behave like a hard reload, ie, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891965/how-to-disable-cache-of-apache

Answer (score 0):

There is actually at least [535 different ways](http://www.phpied.com/files/location-location/location-location.html) to reload a page via javascript, FYI ;).

Have you tried to put *document* on front? `document.location.reload(true);`

Try also this other option:

`window.location.href = window.location.href;`

or

`history.go(0);`

Sure, both are *soft* reload, but seems to work in certain situation.

If nothing works, you have to append random data to the url (like timestamp) to force the download from server, bypassing the cache.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bypass browser taking js files from cache, you need to fetch from server not just files like script.js but rather script.12345.js When you update your file on server, you change file's hash number to let's say script.54321.js And browser understands that the file is different, it must download it again. You can actually use Webpack for this purpose to automate things. In output instead of {filename: bundle.js} you write {filename: bundle.[hash].js}